# 24 VDC door lock with 29 VAC transformer

Tags: power-supply

I have a 24 VDC door lock.  I must use the existing 29 VAC transformer. I've installed a bridge rectifier to change AC to DC, but the voltage didn't drop as I expected it to. Should I use a resistor?  If so what size resistor do I need?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "door lock" If it just a simple passive component, r is i an electric unit with an user interface

Comment: Please explain _”but the voltage didn't drop as I expected it to”_. Why do you expect it to drop?

Comment: What about using a linear voltage regulator for 24 V DC? You should know how much current is needed by the door lock.

Answer (score 2):

What voltage are you reading? Depending on the input voltage range of the door bell it might be okay, though you'll probably want some capacitance to "smooth" out the humps. If you're trying to make a regulated 24V from the output of your rectifier you could use a [buck converter module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09YS6CCSD) sized to the current draw of the door lock.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a resistor to drop the voltage but you can't know what size without knowing the current draw of the lock. If you know how much current it will draw you can figure out the resistance using Ohm's Law.
$$R=\frac{E}{I}$$

where $$E=Rectifier~output~voltage-24V$$
and $$I=Load~current$$

Assuming the lock is a simple solenoid, with it un-energized you will still measure the rectifier voltage as there will be no load, when energized the load current will cause a voltage drop across the resistor.

You will need to size the wattage of the resistor according to the power it will dissipate.
$$P=I^2 \cdot R$$
or
$$P=\frac{V^2}{R}$$
or
$$P=V \cdot I$$
where I is the current and V is the voltage drop across the resistor. Add in a safety factor, for example if the resistor will dissipate 5 W use a 7 W or better yet a 10 W resistor.

You might also consider a filter capacitor (this will affect the rectifier output voltage that you need to do the calculations with) so that the solenoid isn't being fed with pulsating DC, and some kind of reverse EMF protection such as a diode across the solenoid if it doesn't already have one, maybe not absolutely necessary with a simple power supply but it could protect the rectifier diodes from voltage spikes when the solenoid is switched.

Answer (score 0):

The 29 VAC with full wave bridge and capacitor would be about 38 VDC open circuit. Under load it will probably drop to about 32 VDC, although this depends on just what current the electric door lock draws, as well as the impedance of the transformer (which can be very high for a doorbell type). One thing you could try is a single diode and capacitor for half wave rectification. The peak voltage with no load will still be about 38 VDC, but under load it should drop to something like 15 VDC. This might work well for a door lock, where the high voltage on the capacitor will serve to provide a surge of current to pull in the solenoid, and then the lower voltage should be enough to provide the holding current. It might be a good idea to add a diode across the coil to take care of the inductive energy when the switch is released.

Half wave rectifier simulation with 100 uF capacitor and 100 ohm load shows about 24 VDC. But that assumes the load is 100 ohms and the 29 VAC source has negligible impedance.

[image: Half wave rectifier simulation]